# javascript, d3 save svg as png loses color and font

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, png

I have svg-png almost working perfectly client side, just in javascript/d3 it all works, but it loses large amounts of detail. Can anyone shed light on why this might be?:
The original image is:

[image: originalimage]

```
var svg = document.querySelector( "svg" );
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( svg );

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = d3.select("svg").attr("width");
canvas.height = d3.select("svg").attr("height");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = document.createElement( "img" );
img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa( svgData ) );

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

    var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    console.log(canvasdata)
    var pngimg = '<img src="'+canvasdata+'">'; 
    d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);

    var a = document.createElement("a");

    a.download = "name"+".png";
    a.href = canvasdata;
    console.log(a.click())
};
```

The output of that is:

[image: svg-png]

I also tried:

```
  var html = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node().parentNode.innerHTML;
var width = d3.select("svg").attr("width");
var height = d3.select("svg").attr("height");
image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+    btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(html)));
```

but that fails - on the `image.onload()` I get "HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state"

Comment: You're probably setting the styles through CSS. This doesn't generally work well with rendering to PNG; try setting everything directly in the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response - I think I understand: `path` has classes of: `mg-main-area mg-area1 mg-area1-color`. Whats the best way to apply them through css?

Comment: You need to apply the changes to the attributes in the code. You can't use CSS.

Comment: I am using the metrics-graphics library which sets the css. Is there a way to automatically do this with javascript - i.e some sort of way of reading the current css and applying it in to the attributes?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: you could call getComputedStyle on every element and apply all the styles it finds as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Saving an SVG to PNG in the browser will ignore all linked CSS styles applied to the SVG elements.
If you are using d3.js you can add the styles directly to the elements of a particular class using:

```
d3.selectAll(".mg-main-area").style("color","red");
```

For more details see [this article, which I wrote](http://oliverbinns.com/articles/rasterising-SVG-in-the-browser/) about rasterising SVG in the browser.

From the comments it seems you have library applying the CSS, so if you don't want to override the styles manually using d3, you could use jQuery code like the below to pull all CSS elements from a class and apply them as inline styles:

```
$('.mg-main-area').each(function(i, e) {
    var st = e.style;
    var props = [];
    for(var prop in st) { 
        if($(this).css(prop)) {
            props.push(prop + ':' + $(this).css(prop));
        }
    }
    this.style.cssText = props.join(';');
    $(this).children().makeCssInline();
});
```